# How to get rid of array brackets while printing

Tags: swift

While printing an array how to get rid of brackets from left and right?

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
println("\(array)") //It prints [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arrayWithoutBracketsAndCommas = array. //some code

println("\(arrayWithoutBracketsAndCommas)") //prints 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do:

```
extension Array {
    var minimalDescription: String {
        return " ".join(map { "\($0)" })
    }
}

["1", "2", "3", "4"].minimalDescription // "1 2 3 4"
```

---

With Swift 2, using Xcode b6, comes the `joinWithSeparator` method on `SequenceType`:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    ...
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String
}
```

Meaning you could do:

```
extension SequenceType {
    var minimalDescrption: String {
        return map { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

[1, 2, 3, 4].minimalDescrption // "1 2 3 4"
```

**Swift 3:**

```
extension Sequence {
    var minimalDescription: String {
        return map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```