# Swift 3: How to print elements of an array without brackets

Tags: swift

I am trying to print the elements within one print statement e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but without the brackets around the outside of the data. Is this possible?

Comment: Just Iterate over the array and print each element.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach { print($0) }

Comment: Thanks, am I able to use this to also turn all the elements into one string variable?

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
  let arrayName = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

    for element in arrayName {
        print(element, terminator: " ") // output 1 2 3 4 5
    }
```

Ans for your second question -

```
    var string: String?
    for element in arrayName {
        if string == nil {
            string = element
        } else {
        string = string! + ", " + element
        }
    }
    print(string!) // output - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to use the code to add the array elements to one string variable?

Comment: i didn't get you ?

Comment: Lets say I have a variable called testVar. It is possible to make testVar = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? Like the array without the brackets?

Comment: yes it is possible, check my edited ans.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Array {
    var toPrint: String  {
        var str = ""
        for element in self {
            str += "\(element) "
        }
        return str
    }
}

let arrayName = ["1","2","3","4","5"]


print(arrayName.toPrint) // output: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Based on Prema Janoti answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297499/7064692

Better approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093744/7064692